# Maven plugin configuration set parameter to class

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing a maven plugin with a goal that has a parameter of a class.

I want to configure this goal to use a special class.

This is my Mojo of the maven plugin:

```
/**
 * The used parser.
 * 
 * @parameter expression="${parser}"
 */
private EndpointParser parser;

public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
```

This is my pom.xml of the project using the plugin:

```
...
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <parser>com.foo.bar.MyEndpointParser</parser>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
...
```

How do I get it working.

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Is `com.foo.bar.MyEndpointParser` part of your plugin or the project which uses your plugin?

Comment: What is the purpose of the plugin? Why are you using the old style xdoclet things instead of [Java 5 Annotation](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html)?

Comment: @ooxi `MyEndPointParser` is declared in another maven dependency of the calling project.

Comment: See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Mapping_Complex_Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MyEndPointParser` is not part of your plugin but another project (which is not isself a dependency of your plugin) you have to declare it as dependency not of your project but of your plugin e.g.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <parser>com.foo.bar.MyEndpointParser</parser>
        </configuration>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>foo</groupId>
                <artifactId>contains-my-endpoint-parser</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
<configuration>
  <parser implementation="com.foo.bar.MyEndpointParser"/>
</configuration>
```

However, it's probably easier if you configure MyEndpointParser as a `Component`. I can't find any up2date documentation for it. You could have a look at the sources of the maven-compiler-plugin. There you have a parameter for the `compilerId` to switch between implementations.

Comment: make sure it's on the classpath of the plugin.